# HtmlHelper Class Not Found in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

Hi I want to use HtmlHelper in MVC. But it is not recognized. So I try to add **using System.Web.WebPages.Html**. But After I Add this in my code the **AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes** not recognized.  Is it deprecetated or something else?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.WebPages.Html;
namespace TestFrame
{
    internal class IframeBuilder
    {
        internal static HtmlString Iframe(object htmlAttributes)
        {
            IDictionary<string, object> parsedHtmlAttributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);

            TestFrame.IframeId = GetId(parsedHtmlAttributes);

            string parsedIframe = CreateIframeTag(parsedHtmlAttributes);
            parsedIframe += ReceiveMessageScript();
            parsedIframe += SetIframeIdScript();

            return new HtmlString(parsedIframe);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you added the necessary references?

Comment: system.web.mvc do you mean??

Comment: MSDN says [HtmlHelper is in System.Web.Mvc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.anonymousobjecttohtmlattributes(v=vs.118).aspx), not `System.Web.WebPages.Html`.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? I'd suggest you to close and reopen the studio and build the entire project.

Answer (score 1):

`HtmlHelper` is part of `System.Web.Mvc`.
This issue is probably caused when you have either missed to add the `System.Web.Mvc.dll` or the dll is missing or there is some issue with the dll.

> Steps to fix the issue :
>
> 1. Make sure that the dll is added in the reference
> 2. Make sure the dll reference is correct
> 3. Make sure the dll file is present
> 4. Remove the dll and add it again(As suggested by Filburt in comments)

Comment: Could be that the target .NET Framework version doesn't match the Mvc Reference version any more, so suggesting to remove and re-add the System.Web.Mvc reference might also be a step worth to try.

Comment: I agree. That could be the possible reason too. @Filburt